# Iphone Detect each Fingers and Draw Line (Using cocos2d/openGL for Drawing)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I understand the basics of how multi-touch Event works

1. When a figer touches the view/screen that view will receive `ccTouchesBegan` with a set of `UITouch`.
2. `UITouch` will hold the location (`CGPoint`) and its unique for each finger.
3. If more than one finger touches the view at the same time , 2 `UITouch` will be send to the view.
4. Sometime view will receive `ccTouchesBegan`  with 2 `UITouch`'s or `ccTouchesBegan` will be called twise for each finger touch one after another.
5. If finger1 is moving view will receive `ccTouchesMoved` with one `UITouch`.

My question is how to draw lines with each finger touch seperately , put the 1 or 2 fingers on the screen and draw line for each finger touch began/moved/end?

The below code works when there is only single touch but for multi touch it wont work because of the above point 3 and 4.

Exactly like this 
[image]

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([touches count] > 0) {

        // handle multi touch
        UITouch *touch1 = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        CGPoint touchLocation1 = [touch1 locationInView: [touch1 view]];
        touchLocation1 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation1];

        Edge *temEdge1 = (Edge*)[temEdges objectAtIndex:0];
        [[temEdge1 end] updateXY:touchLocation1];
        [[temEdge1 start] updateXY:touchLocation1];

        if ([touches count] > 1) {
            UITouch *touch2 = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
            CGPoint touchLocation2 = [touch2 locationInView: [touch2 view]];
            touchLocation2 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation2];

            Edge *temEdge2 = (Edge*)[temEdges objectAtIndex:1];
            [[temEdge2 end] updateXY:touchLocation2];
            [[temEdge2 start] updateXY:touchLocation2];

        }

    }
}

-(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    if ([touches count] > 0) {

        // handle multi touch
        UITouch *touch1 = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        CGPoint touchLocation1 = [touch1 locationInView: [touch1 view]];
        touchLocation1 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation1];

        Edge *temEdge1 = (Edge*)[temEdges objectAtIndex:0];
        [[temEdge1 end] updateXY:touchLocation1];


        if ([touches count] > 1) {
            UITouch *touch2 = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
            CGPoint touchLocation2 = [touch2 locationInView: [touch2 view]];
            touchLocation2 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation2];

            Edge *temEdge2 = (Edge*)[temEdges objectAtIndex:1];
            [[temEdge2 end] updateXY:touchLocation2];
        }

    }

}

-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([touches count] > 0) {

        // handle multi touch
        UITouch *touch1 = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        CGPoint touchLocation1 = [touch1 locationInView: [touch1 view]];
        touchLocation1 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation1];

        Edge *temEdge1 = (Edge*)[temEdges objectAtIndex:0];
        [[temEdge1 end] updateXY:touchLocation1];

        if ([touches count] > 1) {

            UITouch *touch2 = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
            CGPoint touchLocation2 = [touch2 locationInView: [touch2 view]];
            touchLocation2 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation2];

            Edge *temEdge2 = (Edge*)[temEdges objectAtIndex:1];
            [[temEdge2 end] updateXY:touchLocation2];
        }
    }

}
-(void)draw
{
    [super draw];
    glLineWidth(5.f);
    ccDrawColor4B(0, 0, 255, 255);
    for (Edge *temEdge in temEdges) {
        CGPoint start = [[temEdge start] toCCP];
        CGPoint end   = [[temEdge end] toCCP];
        ccDrawLine(start , end);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to associate arrays of touch positions with different touches(something like NSDictionary with UITouches as keys and NSArrays of points as values). Then you can draw these lines using `ccDrawLine` or any other way if your `draw` method. Just do not forget to store these arrays somwhere where current touch ends.